# Tailwind Modal Image Alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to build a modal using Tailwind in Vue, but am having issues getting the elements inside the modal to align the way I'd like.

I've tried stripping away certain Tailwind classes and tried grids, flex and other such positioning options but the images remain aligned to the left.

Ideally, I'd like the image and some text below it centre-aligned, then two further boxes with those links in it below. Any ideas?

My code looks as follows:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="flex items-center">
      <vue-tailwind-modal
        class="bg-grey-lighter border-b-2 border-grey ml-2 hover:bg-grey-lightest text-grey-darkest font-bold py-4 px-6 rounded "
        :showing="modal"
        @close="modal = false"
      >
        <img class="h-32 w-32 object-center" src="./assets/discord.png" />
        <div
          v-for="item in links"
          :key="item.link"
          class="relative p-8 bg-white w-full max-w-md m-auto flex-col"
        >
          <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
          <div>{{ item.link }}</div>
        </div>
      </vue-tailwind-modal>
      <button @click="toggleModal">Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//import PopUp from "./components/PopUp.vue";
import VueTailwindModal from "vue-tailwind-modal";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueTailwindModal,
    //PopUp,
  },
  data: () => ({
    modal: true,
    links: [
      {
        name: "Google",
        link: "google.com",
      },
      {
        name: "Bing",
        link: "bing.com",
      },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    toggleModal() {
      this.modal = !this.modal;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="flex items-center">
   <vue-tailwind-modal class="flex justify-center items-center bg-grey-lighter border-b-2 border-grey ml-2 hover:bg-grey-lightest text-grey-darkest font-bold py-4 px-6 rounded " :showing="modal" @close="modal = false">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
      <img class="h-32 w-32 object-center" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5658572/pexels-photo-5658572.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
      <div v-for="(item,i) in links" :key="i" class="p-8">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.link }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </vue-tailwind-modal>

      <button @click="toggleModal">Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Adding the display flex to an encompassing `div` , then aligning it so that everything is in the center.